# Program behaves differently when run from C:\Program Files vs outside of that folder?

Tags: winapi, windows-10, windows-shell

Have a strange issue using Win10 x64 Pro.  My program main window hides itself, opens another window for an action, then closes that and the main window shows itself again and set as the foreground Window.   All that works fine, but when the program is run from C:\Program Files the behavior of Windows is not as expected.

If I click on a window of a different process that is behind the main window, it gets the focus but is still visually behind my programs main window.  I can click on another window then things start working as expected.  I can also just click back on my main window then the one in the background and works (but only if I first click on the background window then my main window then the background window again).  However, if I move the same .exe to say d:\test and run it, the problem doesn't occur (I can click on the background window and it shows over the top of my main window like expected).

I tried disabling norton auto-protect, it didn't make any difference.

What could this be, is there some trick I could use get Windows to give the expected results?

Thanks.

Comment: I had someone else test on their w10 system and didn't happen .. maybe some fluke or setting on my system?

Comment: Do you have a reproducible sample? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example